# wp-admin of cloned server with wordpress is logging in at original server's ip address/wp-admin

Tags: ip, wordpress, login

as stated in the re line: wp-admin of cloned server with wordpress is logging in at original server's ip address.

Server A - Original content. IP Address 1
Server B - Cloned Version of Server A. IP Address 2
Server C - Cloned Version of Server B. IP Address 3

When I run:
IP Address 1. I get WP site with LAMPTESTv3
IP Address 2. I get WP site with LAMPTEST
IP Address 3. I get WP site with LAMPTEST

However when I run:
IP Address 2/wp-admin, I get IP Address 1/wp-admin
IP Address 3/wp-admin, I get IP Address 1/wp-admin

Any insight into where I would change the admin files on Server B and/or C so that wp-admin is Server B IP Address/wp-admin instead of Server A IP Address/wp-admin. And same for C.

Thanks for your help.

Kahiga

Answer (score 0):

**You can't just clone a Wordpress site with `mysqldump` and `tar` and move files elsewhere.**

At very minimum, the DB must be edited, and doing it by hand is quite hard, because strings are serialized.

This means that close to each string, there is a (number) that states the lenght of the string, for instance, `(4)word`. If you change `(4)word` to `(4)dog`, it won't work anymore. You have to edit it this way `(3)dog`.

That's why you can't just `sed` or perform any other type of text editor substituion of one of this strings containing the old url with the new one, unless moving from a `www.domain.com` to a `tst.domain.com`, where the serialization of the strings you'll have to edit would be the same, because the URLs are of the same lenght in characters.

And this applies even for the local path: for instance if you where on `/var/www/html` and are moving to `/home/user/www/html` you'll have to reserialize even local path's strings.

Fortunately to perform this substituion there is a (probably more than one, but I use this free one) plugin named [Wp Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/). You'll install it in the old site, and perform a save and substitute of the DB, editing urls and local paths with what will be on the new server; the plugin will take care of the serialization of the strings.

This is a very good resource for both exporting a test site in production or viceversa, and for migrating production sites to a new server or hosting.

> wp-admin of cloned server with wordpress is logging in at original server's ip address

**The reason why you're experiencing what you described is that the DB of the new site still has old site's urls, etc, in it!**

Comment: @TheDahomemman was you able to fix?